# Constructing the coins combination c# code (beginning the loops)

Tags: c#, combinations

I'm trying to solve this task: "Having a coins of 1, 2, and 5 $, check for how many possible ways you will be able to get out of these coins combinations the sum of 10$"

I cannot find the good solution for these as my code shows there's only 7 combinations. Could anyone help me to correct my way of thinking and code?

```
int combination_amount = 0;
int cash_amount = 10;
int a , b , c;
for (a = 0; a < 10; a++)
{
    for (b = 0; b < 5; b++)
    {
        for (c = 0; c < 2; c++)
        {
            if (1 * a + 2 * b + 5 * c == 10)
            {
                combination_amount += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("There is a total number of {0} combinations amount ", combination_amount);
```

Comment: I would start off by adding some diagnostic information to show the combinations it finds. Then if you believe there are more combinations than that, try to work out why they're not being found. (Are you sure there *are* more combinations?) I would also suggest changing your variable names to be more conventional - `cashAmount` rather than `cash_amount` etc.

Comment: Cool! linear optimization problem with a brute force algorithm :p btw, should we consider change to <= instead of using < ?

Comment: I havent reached this "cashAmount" part at my book : ), but I'll surely include this in my future coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the exit condition of your `for` loops, you use "<", which means it will **not** include the limit value, therefore you will be missing solutions like "5 times 2".

Rewrite your loops with "<=" instead of "<", and you should get the correct value.

Comment: Thank You all for Your backup, I guess there ain't much than 10 combinations at this one task, so I'll keep in mind this <= part for sure : ))